# sqlalchemy : inserting only a part of a row

Tags: python, insert, sqlalchemy

I am new to sqlalchemy and run into a problem.
I can't find a way to insert only a part of a new row.
With the `session.add()` I can insert a row if I give all columns. But what if i only want to give some columns?

On the internet, i found some places that told me to use the `.insert()`

```
sqlalchemy.sql.expression.insert(table, values=None, inline=False, **kwargs)
```

(new to programming so I don't fully understand these lines yet)

I imported

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base 
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import insert

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')

class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    password = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, name, password, email):
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
        self.email = email

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()

session.add(users.insert().values(name="some name"))
```

Now this last line keeps giving me an AttributeError, `(Users has no attribute insert)`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A 'partial' insert means just the same as a full insert, but with values you don't specify left as `NULL`. The database can still replace the `NULL` values with a default specified in the schema for columns you omitted.

In SQLAlchemy, that just means you set those same columns to `None`; you don't even have to do that explicitly.

Note that you do *not need* the `__init__` method on your `Users` class. This is probably making it harder for you to not specify some of the columns. The SQLAlchemy declarative base provides you with a default `__init__` method that does what you want *already* but also preserves defaults.

If you don't want to remove `__init__` altogether, either alter that `__init__` method to default to `None` or explicitly specify `None` an column values like Burhan's answer does:

```
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    password = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, name=None, password=None, email=None):
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
        self.email = email
```

then use `session.add(Users())` to insert a completely 'empty' row (which would also work if you *removed* your `__init__` altogether).

Comment: Can you give me an example of how the line of code would look? I found a way to add the full row. but not a correct syntax to only fill some. Problem is i got a table of 50+ columns. which would be annoying to fill in one time

Comment: @HansdeJong: What do you see when you add a 'full row', and what do you *expect* to see? No relational database supports 'partial row' insertions; they just include default values for the columns you omitted.

Comment: So i have to use the way Burhan Khalid suggested? insert 1 full row, and after that just update it?

Comment: The first paragraph is wrong. Unspecified values are completely different to `null` values. 
 IE: in SQL `insert into foo (a, b) values (1, null)` is not the same as `insert into foo (a) values (1)` and for many DBMS the first can raise an error where the second succeeds. The reverse is true: unspecified values may be filled with `null` if the table DDL didn't explicitly set a default. It looks like sqlalchemy understands there _might_ be a default and does not pass `null` where the attribute is `None`. Not sure what caveats there are on sqlalchemy's behaviour here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a [declarative base](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html), you can simply do:

```
u = Users('foo',None,None)
session.add(u)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Jep this was the version i got to work, but as said, I have a table with 50+ columns, than this method will start to get ugly

Comment: What is the actual problem that you have? If your tables are setup with `nullable=True` then you don't really have an issue.